# Uncaught TypeError: this._map is null (Vue.js 3, Leaflet)

Tags: vue.js, leaflet, vuejs3

I am getting a strange error from Leaflet in a Vue.js project (version 3).

If I close a popup and zoom in/out, this error occurs on Firefox:

> Uncaught TypeError: this._map is null

And on Chrome:

> Cannot read property '_latLngToNewLayerPoint' of null

The map component is as follows:

```html
<template>
  <div id="map"></div>
</template>

<script>
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
import L from 'leaflet';

export default {
  name: 'Map',
  data() {
    return {
      map: null
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.map = L.map("map").setView([51.959, -8.623], 12);
    L.tileLayer("https://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(this.map);

    L.circleMarker([51.959, -8.623]).addTo(this.map)
      .bindPopup('I am a marker')
      .openPopup();
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
  #map {
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
  }
</style>
```

**How to reproduce the error:**

1. Open stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-gjeznj
2. Close popup
3. Zoom in/out

Can it be just a bug? Or is there any error in code that I missed?

Comment: Not reproducible. That stackblitz is giving me a blank webpage.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-gjeznj Try this link. Thank you!

Comment: I guess you can use one of these workarounds https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/180977/leaflet-error-when-zoom-after-close-popup-in-lightning-component, sounds like after closing the popup, the `animateZoom` event listener is not removed (maybe it's binded to the circleMarker?), making the zoom not animated should prevent the error (though it's not a real fix)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

FWIW, this seems a new issue since Vue 3.

The problem is absent from Vue version 2 with Leaflet: https://codesandbox.io/s/fast-firefly-lqmwm?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

Just to make sure, here is a reproduction of the issue with the same code but Vue version 3, on CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-mirzakhani-sgeoq?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

What seems to be the culprit is the proxying of `this.map` by Vue, which seems to interfere with Leaflet events (un)binding. It looks like Vue 3 now automatically performs deep proxying, whereas Vue 2 was shallow.

As described in https://v3.vuejs.org/api/basic-reactivity.html#markraw:

> [...] the shallowXXX APIs below allow you to selectively opt-out of the default deep reactive/readonly conversion and embed raw, non-proxied objects in your state graph. They can be used for various reasons:
>
> - Some values simply should not be made reactive, for example a complex 3rd party class instance, or a Vue component object.

...which is the case of Leaflet built `map` object.

A very simple workaround would be not to use `this.map` (i.e. not to store the Leaflet built `map` object in the component state, to prevent Vue from proxying it), but to just store it locally (e.g. `const map = L.map()` and then `myLayer.addTo(map)`).

But what if we *do* need to store the map object, typically so that we can re-use it later on, e.g. if we want to add some Layers on user action?

Then make sure to properly *unwrap* / *unproxy* `this.map` before using it with Leaflet, e.g. using Vue 3 [`toRaw` utility function](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/basic-reactivity.html#toraw):

> Returns the raw, original object of a `reactive` or `readonly` proxy. This is an escape hatch that can be used to temporarily read without incurring proxy access/tracking overhead or write without triggering changes.

```js
import { toRaw } from "vue";

export default {
  name: "Map",
  data() {
    return {
      map: null,
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    const map = L.map("map").setView([51.959, -8.623], 12);
    L.tileLayer("https://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
      attribution:
        '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
    }).addTo(map);

    L.circleMarker([51.959, -8.623])
      .addTo(map)
      .bindPopup("I am a marker")
      .openPopup();

    this.map = map;
  },
  methods: {
    addCircleMarker() {
      L.circleMarker([
        51.959 + Math.random() * 0.05,
        -8.623 + Math.random() * 0.1,
      ])
        .addTo(toRaw(this.map)) // Make sure to "unproxy" the map before using it with Leaflet
        .bindPopup("I am a marker")
        .openPopup();
    },
  },
}
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-colden-g7ju9?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

Comment: I really appreciated the detailed explanation. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Having read [arieljuod](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1430810/arieljuod)'s link, it seems that the only option, *without tweaking Leaflet's js. file*, is to disable zoom animations.

```
this.map = L.map("map", {zoomAnimation: false})
```

If animations are needed, a minor tweak in Leaflet's js file is proposed here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/181000

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @ghybs is completely correct, it is caused by deep proxying of refs.

An alternative solution would be to simply use a shallowRef whenever your ref contains Leaflet data.  AFAIK, it doesn't look like there is a way to create a shallowRef if we use the Options API.  So here is a version of your code using composition API, with a shallowRef:

```
<template>
  <div id="map"></div>
</template>

<script setup>
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
import L from 'leaflet';
import { shallowRef, onMounted } from 'vue';

const map = shallowRef();

onMounted(() => {
  map.value = L.map("map").setView([51.959, -8.623], 12);
  L.tileLayer("https://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
  }).addTo(map.value);

  L.circleMarker([51.959, -8.623]).addTo(map.value)
    .bindPopup('I am a marker')
    .openPopup();
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
  #map {
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
  }
</style>
```